# SSMTP with Gmail (Google Apps)

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I want to set up my raid server here at home to use gmail's smtp and an email from my google apps to alert me if there is any issues.

I set up ssmtp, here is my config:

```
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=email@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
#hostname=ALEXANDRIA

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
#FromLineOverride=YES

UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=email@gmail.com
AuthPass=****
```

But every time I try to send I get this error:

ssmtp: Authorization failed (454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problem. Try again later. 14sm88672bwz.5)

I have logged into the account via web, it is not locked down.

Please help me out, I have spent too long trying to figure this out already.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that I had special characters in my email address.

Comment: What sort of special characters?

Comment: I think it's an equals sign `=` that causes issues, but I've also read that plus sign `+` causes problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Gmail is having a problem with it's TLS auth.  I'd do what the message says and try again later.  If it persists for a while, then consider bugging Gmail support about it.  It certainly doesn't seem like it's anything wrong with your end.

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple as with this old article: http://www.sysadminsjourney.com/2008/09/01/use-gmail-as-an-smtp-relay-using-ssmtp archived here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090104204332/http://www.sysadminsjourney.com/2008/09/01/use-gmail-as-an-smtp-relay-using-ssmtp

You are probably not correctly specifying your email or password. (Which is seems I guessed correctly)

The article basically said this:

> ## Use GMail as an SMTP relay using SSMTP
>
> Posted Mon, 09/01/2008 - 21:05 by Justin Ellison
>   On some of your home
>   workstations, and especially on a laptop, setting up a full-blown SMTP
>   server such as Postfix, Sendmail, or Exim might be overkill.  Follow
>   the jump to learn how to setup the lightweight ssmtp to relay all
>   outbound mail through your GMail account by using Gmail as a
>   smarthost.
>
> SSMTP is meant to be a no-frills, secure, and lightweight replacement
>   for a full-blown MTA. Personally, I feel it's best use is on a laptop
>   where you're moving around between networks a lot, and need to send
>   outbound emails from cron or other shell scripts.
>
> By setting up SSMTP, it doesn't matter where you are, sending mail
>   will be sent out over encrypted SMTP to Google's gmail servers. After
>   handing it off, Google's servers do all the routing for you.
>
> Setting up SSMTP is quick and easy - let's get to it. On Ubuntu, run:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ssmtp mailx`
>
> Now, we just need to configure SSMTP. Open up /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf in
>   your favorite editor, and add or update the following lines:

```
#The following line redirects mail to root to your gmail account
root=myemail@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=yes
UseTLS=yes AuthUser=myemail@gmail.com AuthPass=mypassword
```

> That's it! Now, let's try testing it:
>
> `echo "This is a test message." | mailx -s 'Test Message' myemail@gmail.com`
>
> You should now be all setup and ready to go!

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @JoelCoel That is sad; try: http://web.archive.org/web/20090104204332/http://www.sysadminsjourney.com/2008/09/01/use-gmail-as-an-smtp-relay-using-ssmtp

Answer (score -1):

Apparently Google has an interest in verifying some accounts and puts a capcha in the log-in block. Log in to your google account and go to this page to turn of the capcha:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha