# What characters are illegal in password in ssmtp.conf?

Tags: ssmtp

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with the ssmtp package for sendmail. I've read from a [variety](https://superuser.com/q/431539/571125) of [places](https://serverfault.com/a/76115/331028) that you cannot use "special" characters in the password, and I've discovered it's true that I cannot escape nor quote the password. I have only been able to verify alphanumeric passwords in ssmtp.conf to work, but I cannot find this documented anywhere. My question is, what are the allowed/forbidden characters for a password?

Alternatively, is there any other method of escaping? I've tried backslash, single, and double quotes to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seem to be a number of outstanding bugs listed [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?repeatmerged=no&src=ssmtp#_0_3_4) with regards to problematic characters in the `AuthPass` directive:

- bug report [768129](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768129): the hash/pound character <kbd>#</kbd>
- bug report [463196](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=463196): the equals <kbd>=</kbd> and the colon <kbd>:</kbd> characters

and I don't know if that would be the case for ssmtp specifically but generally bad characters to use in passwords are spaces, extended ASCII: è é ê ë etc. and UNICODE. Stick to `a-z A-Z 0-9 .-` and make passwords longer rather than more complex.

Comment: Because of "#" I had opportunity to learn how mail server works by debugging connection manually in telnet :D

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `read_config()` method on [line 883](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/ssmtp/ssmtp.git/tree/ssmtp.c#n883) of the current blob af4d1e58d28fa9450bfc6a80fbacc75ca28c2220 it appears as though an equals sign `=` or a pound hash sign `#` would cause it to silently continue and skip parsing that line of the config file.

```
    /* Make comments invisible */
    if((p = strchr(buf, '#'))) {
        *p = (char)NULL;
    }

    /* Ignore malformed lines and comments */
    if(strchr(buf, '=') == (char *)NULL) continue;
```

I would still like to see an authoritative answer on the subject or a definitive reference to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following workaround:

- feed the password directly in the command line argument

```
ssmtp -ap "Hash#Password" ...
```

- alternatively put the password in an environment variable.

```
ssmtp -ap $PASSWD ...
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I can verify this works. My password has the colon `:` and semicolon `;` characters. It won't work if entered as is in ssmtp.config, but works with this `-ap` method. In some other Ubuntu applications, the config file allows "complicated" characters to be entered using URLENCODE.